# Did dropna() on dataframe, why is the number of rows lower than expected?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

I have a Dataframe where most columns have 10866 non-null values, except a couple of columns with fewer. The column with the least number of non-null values is "keywords" (9373). So when I drop the NA-values from the Dataframe , I expect the number of non-null values for each column to be equal to the number of non-null values in the column with the least non-null values; in this case "keywords".

However, when I apply `df.dropna(inplace = True)`, the number of non-null values in each column is reduced to the number which previously was not even contained in the Dataframe: 8665, not even in the column "keywords", where least non-null values were contained.

How is this possible? And how does the number 8665 come about?

Here is what the original Dataframe looks like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10866 entries, 0 to 10865
Data columns (total 19 columns):
id                      10866 non-null int64
imdb_id                 10856 non-null object
popularity              10866 non-null float64
budget                  10866 non-null int64
revenue                 10866 non-null int64
original_title          10866 non-null object
cast                    10790 non-null object
director                10822 non-null object
keywords                9373 non-null object
overview                10862 non-null object
runtime                 10866 non-null int64
genres                  10843 non-null object
production_companies    9836 non-null object
release_date            10866 non-null object
vote_count              10866 non-null int64
vote_average            10866 non-null float64
release_year            10866 non-null int64
budget_adj              10866 non-null float64
revenue_adj             10866 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(6), object(9)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
```

And here is what the Dataframe looks like after I have dropped the NA

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8665 entries, 0 to 10865
Data columns (total 19 columns):
id                      8665 non-null int64
imdb_id                 8665 non-null object
popularity              8665 non-null float64
budget                  8665 non-null int64
revenue                 8665 non-null int64
original_title          8665 non-null object
cast                    8665 non-null object
director                8665 non-null object
keywords                8665 non-null object
overview                8665 non-null object
runtime                 8665 non-null int64
genres                  8665 non-null object
production_companies    8665 non-null object
release_date            8665 non-null object
vote_count              8665 non-null int64
vote_average            8665 non-null float64
release_year            8665 non-null int64
budget_adj              8665 non-null float64
revenue_adj             8665 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(6), object(9)
memory usage: 1.3+ MB
```

Comment: By default, as long as each row contains a single NaN, the whole row is dropped. It's absolutely possible that 2000+ rows are dropped.

Comment: **Because the default `df.dropna(how='any')` drops any row in which there is even a single NA.** That's why you can easily get fewer non-NA rows. If you don't like the default behavior don't use it, set `thresh` or `how='all'` args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"name": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    1: [1, 2, np.nan],
    2: [1, np.nan, 3], 
    3: [np.nan, 2, 3]})

print(df)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

What do you think the dataframe will look like after `df.dropna`?  By default `pandas` will drop a row in which any column has a null value.  So even though each column only has one null value, all three rows are dropped.  You can change this behavior with the `how`, `thresh` and `subset` arguments to the `dropna` function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html